# How to stop filling a file in for-loop after a certain line

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I decided to write a program for my 3D printer that converts strings to g-code strings. The question is related to the module that cleans the file generated by the slicer from unnecessary garbage, leaving a clean g-code.

The g-code file has the following structure: header, g-code body and footer.
The end of the header and the beginning of the g-code body are always known. In order to find the beginning I use the index (211):

```
for index, line in enumerate(string_list_form_old_file, start=1):
    if index == 202:
        new_file.write(line)
    if index >= 211:
        new_file.write(line)
```

But to predict where the g-code body will end and the footer will start is impossible.

And this is where my problem begins. With this code, the module writes all the lines from line 211 to the new file, including the footer.

How can I stop recording, when I meet a string equal to "G1 E-1.7000 F1800 \ r \ n" - the string in all files is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `break` keyword in python. When used like this

```py
for index, line in enumerate(string_list_form_old_file, start=1):
    if "G1 E-1.7000 F1800" in line:
        break
    if index == 202:
        new_file.write(line)
    if index >= 211:
        new_file.write(line)
```

the program will break out of the `for` loop when it encounters the string `G1 E-1.7000 F1800` in the line.

Note that you can also do a hard comparison against the string including the newline and carriage return characters, but string comparisons are often iffy. However the example above might also break out of the loop if it encounters the string in another context, like a comment.

Comment: I tried such a simple way. Logically everything should work out, but in practice the footer remains in the new file. There are screenshots in my answer

Comment: I apologize for not immediately noticing what you have: 'if "G1 E-1.7000 F1800" in line:'
and I have: 'if line ==' G1 E-1.7000 F1800 \ r \ n ': 'I checked and so and so - the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I tried such a simple way. Logically everything should work out, but in practice the footer remains in the new file.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwzQr.png)

[complite new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ePTp.png)

Answer (score 0):

By long-term search of a bug, I rechecked, and if 'G1 E-1.7000 F1800' is exactly found in the file 1 time. It turned out that no ...